# Problem removing carriage return in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have been looking around this site searching for how to remove unwanted carriage returns. The solutions I found use `strip()` or `rstrip()` to remove them. However these do not seem to work for me. I should also state I am using a Windows machine.

I am scraping data from a site using Selenium and need to remove the carriage returns that are inside a span. I am now accessing the elements content as:

```
span.text.strip()
```

When I then try to write the line to a file it does not seem to remove all carriage returns. I pasted one of the problematic entries into an online tool to see non-printable characters and it shows:
[image]

2 of the problematic strings after running them through `repr()`.

> Mijn katten zijn verlekkerd op natvoer . Voornamelijk dat van Whiskas
> . Helaas is dat vaak kostelijk waardoor de kosten hoog oplopen.
> Dankzij deze actie op bol.com was het betaalbaar en aangenaam om aan
> te kopen :-)\nZowel natvoer als droogvoer eten ze graag van whiskas
> :-)
>
> "Dit is het voer dat we bijna altijd aan onze katten geven. Lang
> geleden dat we het nog ergens anders kochten dan bij Bol, de prijs is
> echt goed voor zo'n grote hoeveelheid voer.\nIk vind de zakjes handig
> omdat het net 1 portie is, je zit dus niet met een blik dat je in de
> ijskast moet bewaren omdat het niet op is."

It seems there is still a \n in them...

Comment: Can you show the `repr` of these strings?

Comment: @snakecharmerb give me a second.

Comment: @snakecharmerb added 2 of them. Looks like there is still an \n in them for some reason.

Comment: `str.strip` only removes characters from the beginning and  end strings (not lines).  To remove embedded newlines too you would need something like `mystring.strip().replace('\n', ' ')`